# Screen resolution supported by Windows XP not showing under Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, resolution, nvidia-graphics-card

Recently I installed windows 7. Everything is fine, except i couldn't get 1280x1024 resolution (only 1024x768). Under Windows XP I didn't have this problem (I've had 1280x1024 resolution). My graphics card is an integrated one (nVidia 7025) and I have installed the latest version of the nVidia driver from nVidia's website (driver version: 306.97). The display is an old HP D2806A Ergo Ultra VGA display which supports 1280x1024 screen resolution.

The question is: how can I get my normal resolution back?

Comment: Starting at screen resolution, under 'advanced settings', tab 'monitor' is and option 'Hide modes that this monitor can not display'. Can you try removing the tick that one?

Comment: It is unticked, but the box is greyed out, so i cant change the value.

Comment: Another important thing: the video card driver what comes with Windows 7 install DVD,can get 1280x1024, but when install the driver from nVidia website (which is required for hardware acceleration) the heighest resolution will be 1024x768

Comment: Try asking nVidia, seems to be an issue at their end.